# Using a string in CS50 library

Tags: c, string, cs50

Hi all I have a question regarding a passing a string to a function in C. I am using CS50 library and I know they are passing string as a char array (char pointer to a start of array) so passing is done by reference. My function is receiving array as argument and it returns array. When I change for example one of the element of array in function this change is reflected to original string as I expect. But if I assign new string to argument, function returns another string and original string is not change. Can you explain the mechanics behind this behaviour.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>


string test(string s);

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("Text: ");
    string new_text = test(text);
    printf("newtext: %s\n %s\n", text, new_text);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

string test(string s)
{
    //s[0] = 'A';
    s = "Bla";
    return s;
}
```

First example reflects change in the first letter on both text and newtext strings, but second example prints out text unchanged and newtext as "Bla"
Thanks!

Comment: Please add code that demonstrates what you mean.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your question.  We at StackOverflow are more than willing to help you, but it would be appreciated if you could post some code and the errors you are getting.

Comment: *"passing is done by reference"* No, C has no pass-by-reference. You are passing a pointer by value. Modifying the pointer itself does not modify the original value, modifying the pointed to array however modifies the same memory.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You pass `text` to the function `test` as a pointer which is ignored and used as a local pointer variable, which the function returns. Nothing happens to `text` so it is printed as what you entered. Note: you commented out the code which changes the first character, making the question muddy, as well is the unclear "first ahnd second example" narrative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is going to take a while.

Let's start with the basics.  In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values including a 0-valued terminator.  IOW, the *string* `"hello"` is represented as the sequence `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}`.  Strings are stored in arrays of `char` (or `wchar_t` for "wide" strings, which we won't talk about here).  This includes *string literals* like `"Bla"` - they're stored in arrays of `char` such that they are available over the lifetime of the program.

Under most circumstances, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", so most of the time when we're dealing with strings we're actually dealing with expressions of type `char *`.  However, this does not mean that an expression of type `char *` *is* a string - a `char *` may point to the first character of a string, or it may point to the first character in a sequence that *isn't* a string (no terminator), or it may point to a single character that isn't part of a larger sequence.

A `char *` may also point to the beginning of a *dynamically allocated* buffer that has been allocated by `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`.

Another thing to note is that the `[]` subscript operator is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic - the expression `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)` - given an address value `a` (converted from an array type as described above), offset `i` elements (*not bytes*) from that address and dereference the result.

Another important thing to note is that the `=` is not defined to copy the contents of one array to another.  In fact, an array expression *cannot* be the target of an `=` operator.

The CS50 `string` type is actually a `typedef` (alias) for the type `char *`.  The `get_string()` function performs a lot of magic behind the scenes to dynamically allocate and manage the memory for the string contents, and makes string processing in C look much higher level than it really is.  I and several other people consider this a bad way to teach C, at least with respect to strings. Don't get me wrong, it's an *extremely* useful utility, it's just that once you don't have cs50.h available and have to start doing your own string processing, you're going to be at sea for a while.

So, what does all that nonsense have to do with your code?  Specifically, the line

```
s = "Bla";
```

What's happening is that instead of copying the contents of the string literal `"Bla"` to the memory that `s` points to, the *address* of the string literal is being written to `s`, overwriting the previous pointer value.  You cannot use the `=` operator to copy the *contents* of one string to another; instead, you'll have to use a library function like `strcpy`:

```
strcpy( s, "Bla" );
```

The reason `s[0] = A` worked as you expected is because the subscript operator `[]` is defined in terms of pointer arithmetic.  The expression `a[i]` is evaluated as `*(a + i)` - given an address `a` (either a pointer, or an array expression that has "decayed" to a pointer as described above), offset `i` elements (*not bytes!*) from that address and dereference the result.  So `s[0]` is pointing to the first element of the string you read in.

Comment: *"such that they are available over the lifetime of the program"* - Nah, you should correct this.

Comment: Thanks this answer clarified my confusion about CS50 string type.

Comment: @Broman -- what is wrong with the statement? [String literals _are_ stored in character arrays of static duration](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6), and an object with static duration has a lifetime which lasts for ["the entire execution of the program."](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p3)

Comment: I have one more follow up question to this answer. So if I declare to different char pointers e.g char *s and char *t and assign to both of them same string literal e.g. "test" both pointers will show to the same address or there will be two different addresses for each literal value? My guess is they will point to the same address.

Comment: @IvanStimac: There's no guarantee either way; the language definition leaves that unspecified.  I would *hope* that all occurrences of a string literal in a single translation unit (preprocessed source file) all map to the same location, but I wouldn't be surprised if a string literal that appears in multiple translation units gets mapped to multiple locations.

Answer (score 2):

This is difficult to answer correctly without a code example. I will make one but it might not match what you are doing.

Let's take this C function:

```
char* edit_string(char *s) {
    if(s) {
        size_t len = strlen(s);
        if(len > 4) {
            s[4] = 'X';
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

That function will accept a *pointer* to a *character array* and if the pointer is not NULL and the zero-terminated array is longer than 4 characters, it will replace the fifth character at index 4 with an 'X'. There are no *references* in C. They are always called *pointers*. They are the same thing, and you get access to a pointed-at value with the *dereference* operator `*p`, or with array syntax like `p[0]`.

Now, this function:

```
char* edit_string(char *s) {
    if(s) {
        size_t len = strlen(s);
        if(len > 4) {
            char *new_s = malloc(len+1);
            strcpy(new_s, s);
            new_s[4] = 'X';
            return new_s;
        }
    }
    s = malloc(1);
    s[0] = '\0';
    return s;
}
```

That function returns a *pointer to* a newly allocated copy of the original character array, or a newly allocated empty string. (By doing that, the caller can always print it out and call `free` on the result.)

It does not change the original character array because `new_s` does not point to the original character array.

Now you could also do this:

```
const char* edit_string(char *s) {
    if(s) {
        size_t len = strlen(s);
        if(len > 4) {
            return "string was longer than 4";
        }
    }
    s = "string was not longer than 4";
    return s;
}
```

Notice that I changed the return type to `const char*` because a string literal like `"string was longer than 4"` is constant. Trying to modify it would crash the program.

Doing an assignment to `s` inside the function *does not change* the character array that s *used to point to*. The pointer `s` points to or references the original character array and then after `s = "string"` it points to the character array `"string"`.